# File cannot be accessed after export (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, file, export, bufferedreader

I know that there are many questions like this out there, but so far there have been none that have been of help.

In eclipse, I have a file inside of my project folder ,and I can get it to load using:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
```

When I export the project it will not load the file because it cannot find the file. I have no idea what is going on. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Your export is not correct. Generally in any IDE, when you select export, it gives you an option what all files you want to export. You must have not selected the desired file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the file, you have two options.

### You Could...

Make sure that the file is in the same directory as the exported `jar` file and/or the same execution context.  This will allow you to use something like `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./" + fileName)))`;

When referencing the file, it need to specify a relative path to the file.

This means you must ensure that the file is copied to the correct location when ever you move the `jar` file.

### You Could...

Embed the file within the `jar` as an embedded resource.  This means that the file becomes part of the `jar` file.  This also means that you can no longer reference it as a `File`, but need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`, for example...

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(this.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/resource")));
```

In order to use this, the file must be placed within the `resources` directory within your Eclipse project and the directory included within your build path

---

If you want to be able to write to the file, then you MUST use option one.  Embedded resources can not be written to (without a lot of work)